# Bootstrap-Select with live search ONLY

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [Bootstrap-Select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) with live search but cant manage to do it without select, I mean only to display search input and results. Is there any way this can be done?

```js
$('select').selectpicker();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.18/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.18/js/bootstrap-select.min.js">
</script>


<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>





<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Barbecue</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you have in mind? Do you want to hide all `option` ?